# Disable NIC Receive Side Scaling hashing

Tags: performance, linux-networking, udp

On a benchmark lab system running Fedora Core 27 I've got Intel X710 10GE cards and 12-core Xeon processors, configured with 12 NIC queues and RX Flow Hashing based on both IP addresses and port numbers.

This results in uneven balancing between cores, and inconsistent performance results.  I've got `irqbalance` disabled, with a 1:1 mapping from NIC queue to CPU core configure via `/proc`.

My application is UDP based so I'm not really bothered about the hashing.  I can't generate enough entropy across the inputs to the hash function to get an even distribution of outputs, so I'd quite like to just try plain round robin instead.

Is there a way to disable RSS for UDP and get round robin whilst still maintaining separate queues?   All of the links I've found that talk about disabling RSS also seem to disable multiple queues.